# QGIS refresh layer at interval

Tags: qgis, geojson, vector-layer, refresh

I am trying to understand the behavior of Layer->Render-> Refresh layer at interval in QGIS

1. I sat up a flask rest api which serves a geojson.
2. I added the geojson to QGIS via Add Layer->
   a. Protocol HTTP/cloud/etc
   b. Type: HTTP
   c.URI: localhost/points.geojson
   The points are represented on the map correctly
3. I changed the layer->Properties->Rendering-> Refresh layer at interval (5 sec)

I would have expected that there would be a call every 5 seconds towards the server and the map data would be updated accordingly. But the layer does not get refreshed. I don't see any changes neither when I remove a point from the json file on my local drive, nor if I change an attribute. If I press F5 then the canvas refreshes and it automatically loads the new data and I can see the changes. Is this the behavior that is wanted or am I misunderstanding the function of this tool? It seems like the data is cached somewhere?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class point(Resource):

    def get(self):
        with open('C:/points/venv/src/points.geojson') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
        return data

api.add_resource(point,"/points.geojson")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```